# NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined even though it's installed

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Just so we're clear, numpy is installed.
I can see numpy listed in the result of `conda list`.

However, importing it gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Try running '!pip install numpy' in a cell directly above 'import numpy'

Comment: @Asaad you need to import numpy package. Here you have not imported numpy. First you try to execute 1st line ("import numpy")

Comment: Yup, you're right @python_user, looks like I was running the bottom row without running the top one.